# How to export worksheet vba code to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy whole VBAProject to another workbook. I managed to find how to copy and paste modules and user forms but have problem with Microsoft Excel Objects.

Is there a way to export worksheets macro code with another macro?

Comment: Have you tried using `Worksheet.Copy` to copy the whole worksheet, code/data/objects/formatting and all to the new Workbook?

Comment: Probably the search you should be looking for would be export/import worksheet vba code

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: Probably duplicating the current workbook (with the VBA code) and importing/moving the worksheets from another workbook is simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but it didn't solve my problem. I need to copy only the vba code from a given worksheet, not the whole worksheet.

Comment: Please be more clear which code exactly you mean. You are mixing up the terms "workbook" and "worksheet". Please clarify.

Comment: Clarification: I meant that i need to copy only the vba part of the worksheet (which i see in VBA Editor after clicking "Sheet1") without the data that is on this worksheet (which i see in Excel standard view)